# How to do reverse URL search in Django namespaced reusable application

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Consider that I include namespaced reusable application:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ella urls
    url('^ella/', include('ella.core.urls', namespace="ella")),
)
```

Now, the Ella applications has urls like that:

```
urlpatterns = patterns( '',
    url( r'^(?P<category>[a-z0-9-/]+)/$', category_detail, name="category_detail" ),
    # object detail
    url( r'^(?P<category>[a-z0-9-/]+)/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{1,2})/(?P<day>\d{1,2})/(?P<content_type>[a-z0-9-]+)/(?P<slug>[a-z0-9-]+)/$',
        object_detail, name="object_detail" )
)
```

Now, calling `{% url ella:category_detail category="cat" %}` works fine. However, when object tries to generate link to it's details, it calls

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse('object_detail', kwargs={'required' : 'params'})
```

This is not working, unless rewritten as

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
url = reverse('ella:object_detail', kwargs={'required' : 'params'})
```

So, if I understand it correctly, **including reusable application into namespace breaks all inner reverse()s inside given application**.

Is it true? What have I missed? Is there any way around?

Answer (score 7):

Since you have name-spaced url configuration, you need to mention namespace:view-name pattern in order to reverse it properly (especially from view).

But, if you want to avoid this, you may also pass namespace/appname as current_app parameter.
There are multiple ways to specify current_app when you are in template. But if you are in view, you need to hard-code as you did, or pass to current_app parameter

```
url = reverse('object_detail', 
              kwargs={'foo':'bar'}, 
              current_app=app_name_or_name_space)
```

refer: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse

Comment: I think the real question is: is there a way to include a third party reusable app with a URL namespace and not need to rewrite all the calls to the reverse() function inside the reusable app.

Comment: Yup, exactly. current_app is same hardcode as prefix:...but thanks for the trick.

Comment: Agreed. But, How to get the current app name? is there such, otherwise how really pluggable apps work.

Answer (score 1):

> URL Namespaces can be specified in two ways.
>
> Firstly, you can provide the application and instance namespace as arguments to include() when you construct your URL patterns. For example,:
>
> (r'^help/', include('apps.help.urls', namespace='foo', app_name='bar')),

This is right from http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#defining-url-namespaces.

Try changing `include('ella.core.urls', namespace="ella")` to `include('ella.core.urls', namespace="ella", app_name="ella")`.  I'm not 100% this will work, but its worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Django 1.8 you can write something like this:

`url = reverse('%s:object_detail' % request.resolver_match.namespace, kwargs={'required' : 'params'})`

`request.resolver_match.namespace` is a string containing the namespace of the currently running view.