# Django Redirecting passing one (or more) object(s) as argument(s)

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

Context: I have 3 apps
A, B and C

each one have views.py and urls.py files

views.py

A has do_Ax(request, xpto), do_Ay(request, xpto), do_Az(request, xpto)

B has do_Bx(request), do_By(request), do_Bz(request)

C has do_Cx(request, xpto), do_Cy(request, xpto), do_Cz(request, xpto)

urls.py
A

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^A_x/$', views.do_Ax, name='A_x'),
                       url(r'^A_y/$', views.do_Ay, name='A_y'),
                       url(r'^A_z/$', views.do_Az, name='A_z'),
```

B

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^B_x/$', views.do_Bx, name='B_x'),
                       url(r'^B_y/$', views.do_By, name='B_y'),
                       url(r'^B_z/$', views.do_Bz, name='B_z'),
```

C

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^C_x/$', views.do_Cx, name='C_x'),
                       url(r'^C_y/$', views.do_Cy, name='C_y'),
                       url(r'^C_z/$', views.do_Cz, name='C_z'),
```

the entry point to my global app is through B. There, I check some stuff and want to **REDIRECT** to A or C view's correct method with the new argument...
Is there a way I can accomplish this?

I've tried a n00b approach but I get a SuspiciousOperation Exception ("Unsafe redirect to URL with scheme ...")

IMPORTANT:
I also a a "parent" app named **top** which has the following urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^A/', include('apps.top.A.urls', namespace="A")),
    url(r'^B/', include('apps.top.B.urls', namespace="B")),
    url(r'^C/', include('apps.top.C.urls', namespace="C")),
)
```

PLEASE NOTE  >>>>> **XPTO** is an object!!!! not a textual value! <<<<<<<<

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django import shortcuts

def do_Bx(request):
    # do some tests here and whatever
    xpto = whatever
    url = reverse("A_x", args=[xpto])
    return shortcuts.redirect(url)
```

Comment: I was editing when you answered.. I was near your approach, will give it a try. THanks :)

Comment: Django doesnt seem to find A (or C) app... it seems so simple yet I'm failing to accomplish this.. by the way A,B and C are all "child" apps of top and are all 3 at the same "level"

Comment: Exception: Reverse for 'A_x' with arguments '((<xpto>),)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to specify the namespace on the reverse() call, since your parent app's urls.py defines them:

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3578922/147072):

```
url = reverse('A:A_x', args=[xpto])
```