# How can I reverse django admin url with url parameters to prepopulate some fields?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have Transaction app and Transaction model. Transaction model has foreign key to User model. I noticed that I can prepopulate some fields with data through GET parameters. For example to choose user for my transaction in admin form I can use this url:

```
transactions/transaction/add/?user=1
```

It work fine, but I want to user reverse function to generate that kind of urls.

Tried this:

```
from django.urls import reverse
reverse('admin:transactions_transaction_add', kwargs={'user': 1})
```

But got this error:

```
Reverse for 'transactions_transaction_add' with arguments '()' 
and keyword arguments '{'user': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
tried: ['admin/transactions/transaction/add/$']
```

I made this work to use concatenate generated link:

```
change_url = reverse(
        "admin:transactions_transaction_add",
    ) + "?user=" + str(obj.pk)
```

But would be very kind to know if the more clear solution for this.
Note that 'transactions/transaction/add/?user=1' works just fine if use it from browser, error appears for reverse function.

Thanks!

Comment: But concatenating *is* the answer. Django URL patterns don't include querystring parameters.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Works just fine so I left it as is.

Answer (score -1):

Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578922/how-to-do-reverse-url-search-in-django-namespaced-reusable-application) from a previous asked question.

```
url = reverse('object_detail', 
              kwargs={'foo':'bar'}, 
              current_app=app_name_or_name_space)
```

or try the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)